# How to register and show 2nd sidebar only if the screen is wider than 1682px in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show a 336px width second sidebar (left side on all pages) for destop/tv screens wider than 1682px.

If the second sidebar has its own class then I can hide it with the {display: none;} CSS tag inside the media query feature.

Currently, my template only has 1 sidebar which can be shown either on the right side or left side. It is currently on the right side.

This script is already present on my functions.php

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
//  Register widgetized areas, including two sidebars and four widget-ready columns in the footer.
//  To override skeleton_widgets_init() in a child theme, remove the action hook and add your own
//  function tied to the init hook.
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

if ( !function_exists( 'skeleton_widgets_init' ) ) {

function skeleton_widgets_init() {
        // Area 1, located at the top of the sidebar.
        register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Posts Widget Area', 'smpl' ),
        'id' => 'sidebar-1',
        'description' => __( 'Shown only in Blog Posts, Archives, Categories, etc.', 'smpl' ),
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget-container %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );


    // Area 2, located below the Primary Widget Area in the sidebar. Empty by default.
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Pages Widget Area', 'smpl' ),
        'id' => 'sidebar-2',
        'description' => __( 'Shown only in Pages', 'smpl' ),
        'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget-container %2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );

    // Area 3, located in the footer. Empty by default.
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'First Footer Widget Area', 'smpl' ),
        'id' => 'footer-widget-area-1',
        'description' => __( 'The first footer widget area', 'smpl' ),
        'before_widget' => '<div class="%1$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );

    // Area 4, located in the footer. Empty by default.
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Second Footer Widget Area', 'smpl' ),
        'id' => 'footer-widget-area-2',
        'description' => __( 'The second footer widget area', 'smpl' ),
        'before_widget' => '<div class="%1$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );

    // Area 5, located in the footer. Empty by default.
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Third Footer Widget Area', 'smpl' ),
        'id' => 'footer-widget-area-3',
        'description' => __( 'The third footer widget area', 'smpl' ),
        'before_widget' => '<div class="%1$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );

    // Area 6, located in the footer. Empty by default.
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name' => __( 'Fourth Footer Widget Area', 'smpl' ),
        'id' => 'footer-widget-area-4',
        'description' => __( 'The fourth footer widget area', 'smpl' ),
        'before_widget' => '<div class="%1$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );
}

/** Register sidebars by running skeleton_widgets_init() on the widgets_init hook. */

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'skeleton_widgets_init' );

}

/** Next code follows from this point...
```

This is the code present on sidebar.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The Sidebar containing the primary blog sidebar
 *
 */

// hide sidebars with sidebars=false custom field
if (is_singular() && get_post_meta($post->ID, "sidebars", $single = true) ==  "false") {
    return;
}

if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) {
        do_action('skeleton_before_sidebar');
        dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' );
        do_action('skeleton_after_sidebar');
}

?>
```

As per this guide, https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/135403/display-sidebar-that-created-in-functions-php , I added the code of the first answer to the functions.php file

```
// 2nd Sidebar
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpsites_add_widget' );

function wpsites_add_widget() {

register_sidebar(array(
'name'=>'Sidebar-Aries',
'id' => 'sidebar-aries',
'description' =>'Display all the contents of sidebar at Aries page.',
'before_widget' => '',
'after_widget' => '',
'before_title' => '',
'after_title' => '',
));
}
```

Then added the other code into the single.php file

```
<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying all single posts.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage skeleton
 * @since skeleton 0.1
 */

get_header();
do_action('skeleton_before_content');
get_template_part( 'loop', 'single' );
do_action('skeleton_after_content');
get_sidebar();
get_footer();

<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-aries' ) ) : ?>
<ul id="sidebar">
    <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-aries' ); ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
?>
```

Then I visited Appearance > Widgets and checked if there is any new sidebar but there is none.

I also tried the code from another question but it didn't work for me as well.

Then I followed this guide - https://smallbusiness.chron.com/build-website-php-sidebar-60499.html

> Step: 5 - Locate the lines of code that register the sidebars in
> "functions.php" -- they are usually near the top. Edit the code to
> make “register_sidebar” plural, and add a number “2” between the
> brackets in the line below, like this:

`if ( function_exists('register_sidebars') ) register_sidebars(2);`

> Click "Update File." The sidebar is now available by going to
> "Appearance" and then "Widgets."

But the code present on my functions.php looks a bit different and it didn't work.

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**STEP I:** Open the `functions.php` and paste the following codes:

```php
  function __widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array (
    'name' => __('2nd Sidebar', 'textdomain'),
    'id' => 'sidebar-secondary',
    'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget-container %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => "</li>",
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ) );
  }
  add_action( 'widgets_init', '__widgets_init' );
```

**STEP II:** Now, copy the `sidebar.php` and paste it and rename it into: `sidebar-secondary.php`. Now erase all the codes inside, and paste the following:

```php
    <aside id="sidebar-secondary-wrapper" role="complementary">
      <?php if ( is_active_sidebar('sidebar-secondary') ) : ?>
        <div id="secondary" class="widget-area">
          <ul class="xoxo">
            <?php dynamic_sidebar('sidebar-secondary'); ?>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <?php endif; ?>
    </aside>
```

**STEP III:** Get into the `index.php` or any other files you want. Paste the code `get_sidebar( 'secondary' );` in the appropriate places in the `get_sidebar();` or `get_footer();` sections as follows::

```php
<?php get_header();
// paste here: get_sidebar( 'secondary' );
...
...
```

or

```php
<?php get_header();
...
...
// paste here: get_sidebar( 'secondary' );
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
?>
```

**STEP IV:**
Now your layout consists of two sidebars. Rest is up to you.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1681px) {
  #secondary-sidebar-wrapper {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. The code successfully registers a new sidebar but whatever added to the 2nd sidebar is displayed below the 1st sidebar on the right side. Instead of the 2nd sidebar being in the left side (or both sidebar next to each other on the right side).